# Returning Objects with toString() method

Tags: java, class

I have a main method that is calling a class method;

```
CourseListQ2 list = new CourseListQ2();

list.addCourse(new Course("Structure and Modelling", "Chemistry", 1));
list.addCourse(new Course("Design in Engineering", "Engineering", 1));
......
```

In this class that I wrote, I created an array of objects from the main method, and subsequently expanded it and deleted values I didn't need. Then, I wrote a `toString` method that was suppose to return each object on a new line:

```
public String toString(){
      return  Arrays.toString(arrayCourses) ;}
```

However, it's returning the entire array on a single line. So obviously, I'm misinterpreting what this method does exactly.

I have two ideas, either I'm suppose to try to return each as an object, like getName().toString(arrayCourses) + getYear().toString(arrayCourses) + "\n",

Or, maybe I'm suppose to create a loop that adds a new line. Yet I think this defeats the purpose of having the `toString` method, and it still returns a '[' at the beginning of the output.

So, could anyone explain why this is happening and perhaps suggest a better approach?

Comment: Just write your own `toString()` method. Sounds like you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm misinterpreting what this method does exactly.

`Arrays.toString` formats an array as a single `String`, with string representations of individual elements separated by commas.

> Either I'm suppose to try to return each as an object, like `getName().toString(arrayCourses) + getYear().toString(arrayCourses) + "\n"`

That's not going to solve the problem entirely, because the commas inserted by `Arrays.toString` would remain there. Generally, it's not a good idea to append `'\n'` in your `toString` implementation, because it makes an assumption about the way the string is going to be used by the callers.

> Or, maybe I'm suppose to create a loop that adds a new line.

That's a better idea. Use `StringBuilder`, and call its `append` method twice - first for the object, and second for the `\n` character.

Note: rather than appending `'\n'` directly, use `System.getProperty("line.separator");` to get the system-specific line separator.

```
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
for (Course c : arrayCourses) {
    res.append(c);
    res.append(newLine);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example `Arrays.toString(arrayCourses)` you are calling the toString() method of the Arrays class, below is what [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28boolean%5B%5D%29) says about that method:

> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified
>   array. The string representation consists of a list of the array's
>   elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are
>   separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space).
>   Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(float). Returns
>   "null" if a is null.

For the approach i would suggest what @dasblinkenlight adviced.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong on using loop in `toString()` method. However if you use Java8 you can use [String.join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-). So if you want to have just each element on one line use

```
return String.join('\n', arrayCourses);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java every object has a toString() method (if you didn't write one there is a default one provided)

If we try to run the toString() on a collection object it runs the toString() method on all the objects and prints them between [], separated by a ','.

If you would like to have your own implementation then I suggest to override the toString() of the method to print the values the way you want